# Openoffice Installation and the results?

Tags: installation, openoffice.org

My question for this time, involves Open office application. I have the sources of how to install openoffice on ubuntu os. The apache home site or the main home of the  program provider and parent owner. It seems like there are a lot of steps involved in order to install Open office 3.4. I have done the necessary steps. Ohhh yeah I did remove Libreoffice. I promise. It's all gone.

Here is what I did

1-went to parent site.http://www.openoffice.org/download/

2-I downloaded the necessary/proper file

3-I transferred it to the main directory home folder.

4.I extracted the file with the terminal, with the tar -xzvf file extension.

5.I got a new file called "en-us". Located in the home directory.

6.What do I do know. I opened the file folder. The en usa. I see three files. I have opened the deb folder. I see a whole lot of folders, but I am unsure what to do here from this point on.

I am trying to get all the software working as one. Let it be the writer, powerpoint and the rest of the programs from the Openoffice suite. If someone out there knows what I should do now. Please suggest notes or detailed.

Comment: There should be a readme type of file with instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Installation Guide](http://www.openoffice.org/download/common/instructions.html) and the [Installation FAQs](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Installation).